# How to Profile the CPU Activity of a Visual Studio Program

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging, monitoring

Imagine i have a program doing a lot of things wasting about 90% of CPU.
I need a way to know (through visual studio) where the program are wasting CPU.

Comment: Only 10% is wasted, good job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Visual Studio Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx).

You can get performance reports that show which functions are most expensive CPU-wise.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Rational Purify Plus](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purifyplus/win/): it includes a tool to analyze CPU utilization (it was previously sold separately as Rational Quantify).